# How to do hypothesis testing for two different counts?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, poisson-distribution, count-data, z-test

I have the following problem: in year A, we observe that a company sold N_A of its product, in year B, we observe that the company sold N_B of its products. How do I do hypothesis testing that the company sold statistically different number of products in year A and B?

My thought is that

```
     N_A ~ Poisson(lambda_A)
     N_B ~ Poisson(lambda_B)
```

So my hypothesis test is

```
     H_0: lambda_A = lambda_B
     H_1: lambda_A != lambda_B
```

Then I can run a z-test where the test statistic

```
     Z = |N_A - N_B|/sqrt(N_A + N_B)
```

follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

Is this the correct method? If so, why can the Z-test be applied in this case?

Comment: That is not a statistic because it isn't a function of the data.

Comment: @EricMittman thanks for pointing out my mistake! just corrected my Z statistics

Comment: You cannot statistically test for a diffference because you have just 1 data point in each of your comparison groups.

Comment: @mkt, even a single point can be an estimate of a distribution mean (albeit, not a very good one). Moreover, if you assume the distributions are Poisson, you have an estimate of the variance. Thus, it is possible to conduct such a test, it is just that this test makes very strong assumptions that cannot be assessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the Poisson distribution, we get that the "noise" in the measurements is proportional to the square root of the expected value. This is a pretty major assumption.

The expected value of the difference of two i.i.d. random variables are zero and the variance of the difference is twice the variance of one of them.

Further, if we assume that the distribution of the difference is approximately normal -- which seems reasonable for large Poisson counts -- we end up with this z-statistic.

Comment: Because counts are typically overdispersed relative to the Poisson, it is best to take the resulting p-value as the lower bound, rather than an accurate p-value. Still, this procedure is used on occasion.

Comment: @gung, can you explain why counts are typically overdispersed relative to the Poisson?

Comment: They don't *have* to be, @Amazonian, they just almost always are. That's an empirical fact (really, observation). Basically, counts will be overdispersed relative to the Poisson if there is >1 component to the data generating process. Eg, the negative binomial is often used to model overdispersed counts, but NB is a mixture of Poisson distributions w/ lambdas distributed as Gamma.

Comment: @gung can you please explain how to empirically measure the dispersion of counts and empirically compare them to that of a Poisson RV? In other words, what kind of data would I need and how to visualize this?

Comment: @Amazonian, well, you would need more than 1 datum per group. That should be a new question, though. That isn't the sort of thing that should be buried in comments. Search the site first; that's the sort of thing that may already have been covered.

Answer (score 0):

Statistical testing is meaningless here as you have no measure of variability. All you have is just two data points, one for company A and for company B.

Comment: Even a single point can be an estimate of a distribution mean (albeit, not a very good one). Moreover, if you assume the distributions are Poisson, you have an estimate of the variance. Thus, it is possible to conduct such a test, it is just that this test makes very strong assumptions that cannot be assessed.